# UITableView in UIPopover hides content while displaying keyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have a UITableView embedded in a UIPopoverController, as shown below.

[image: PopoverController in 'normal' state]

When I select a cell, the textField in the cell becomes firstResponder. But instead of keeping the tableview scrolled to the top, all content goes away (even though there are no more than 4 cells). It is impossible to scroll to the top will this happens. After dismissing the keyboard everything is normal again.

[image: PopoverController while the keyboard is shown]

The following code does not resolve the problem:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CRShoppingListItemCell *cell = (CRShoppingListItemCell *) [tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.itemTextField.enabled = YES;
    cell.itemTextField.delegate = self;
    [cell.itemTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    [tableView scrollToNearestSelectedRowAtScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: What is the resizingMask of your tableView ?

Comment: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you aren't using the UITableViewController. Inside that controller's viewWillAppear it checks for isInViewControllerThatHandlesKeyboardAvoidance (private) and one of those controllers is the popover controller. So if it is that then the keyboard avoiding behaviour you would usually want when the table is full screen is turned off.